# Self learning data evaluation in Python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, evaluation

I have about 300.000 images - all categorized manually as "clip art" or "photo". For each image I can calculate three independent, numerical features that give a clear hint about whether the image is indeed a clip art or a photo. None of these numbers *alone* is enough for auto-categorizing new images reliably. Used in combination, however, auto-categorizing should be pretty accurate.

I can manually fiddle around and test hundreds of images and observe data. Thus, I can empirically find more or less suitable weighing factors or something alike. But I do have 300.000 properly categorized data sets ... I should be able to use this data to categorize new images pretty reliably. But how? I don't even know the proper terms to Google for an answer: is it "self learning" or a "neural network" or "artificial intelligence" that I'm looking for? How do I start in Python to solve this?

Comment: You are looking for machine learning (supervised learning since you have the category). There is a lot of techniques though svm seems to work most of the time.

Comment: I think that the downwote is because the question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task is called *classification* and is a part of *machine learning*. [This](http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/machine-learning/machine-learning-the-basics/) seems to be a very brief introduction to this field.

I don't know of a handy python library (I'm not saying there are none, but I don't use such things so I don't know of any), but some ML algorithms and classification models are very easy to implement yourself (e.g. k-NN, or linear classifier/regressor).

Comment: Thanks, even the term "machine learning" helps. I'm currently studying your recommended read.

Comment: @SimonSteinberger Scikit maybe a good library to look at for your task -http://scikit-learn.org/stable/

Comment: @New2WebDevelopment: Already on it :-) Seems to be perfect for the task. Thanks!